# MVC в сайте-портфолио

Tags: php, mvc

Допустим, GET-запрос:

```
index.php?option=works...
```

запускается контроллер works. как дальше связывать это с моделью, а потом видом?  спасибо

Comment: создайте модель и сделайте вывод в вид ее из контроллера.

Comment: подскажите вкратце как?

Comment: @ModaL тут дело не в фрэймворках. MVC не фреймворк. Вообщем зайдите в вики про mvc, почитайте. Must know. Впрочем для портфолио mvc тоже не к чему

Comment: Прочитайте здесь http://habrahabr.ru/post/31270/

Answer (score 1):

```
index.php?option=works...
```

Вообще то, это на ваше усмотрение,какую модель вызывать.

Примерно так,предположим что у нас есть класс `Works` (описанный в `model/works.php`),
тогда создаем :

```
$work = new Model_Works();//(Model-это каг бы каталог,и дальше сам и файлик).
```

Для видов,тоже ,аналогично.

Для загрузки классов обычно используеться [автолоадер](http://php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload.php)

PS.Я бы рекомендовал бы вам посмотреть как работают фреймворки [Kohana](http://kohanaframework.org/),[Yii](http://www.yiiframework.com/),etc.И вообще, для портфолио обычно и Wordpress устраивает во всем плане.